# node-postgres returning multiple array_length() columns?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have 3 array columns and i am trying to get the count for each of these arrays but node-postgres is only returning one of them which is the last array_length() passed in the SQL statement. I passed the same sql query using the postgres console and it returned all the results.

Comment: PostgreSQL and node_postgres versions? Exact query text and exact output text? Sample data? Unless someone here has psychic powers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured it out, the array query needs to be wrapped in brackets

```
(array_length(friends,1),array_length(clients, 1),array_length(venues, 1))
```

and this will return for e.g `(3,3,7)`, otherwise only the last query will return `(7)`.